# To Transpose the different data only from rows to columns in excel

Tags: excel

is there any way to convert the data from horizontal to vertical in excel as below?

```
a   b   c               
1   100 600             
1   200 500             
1   300 700 





a   b   c   b1  c1  b2  c2
1   100 600 200 500 300 700
```

Comment: Are you looking for a formula solution, or VBA?

Answer (score 0):

With data in columns **B** and **C**, pick any cell and enter:

```
=OFFSET($B$1,ROUNDUP(COLUMNS($A:A)/2,0)-1,MOD(COLUMNS($A:A)-1,2))
```

and copy across:

[image]

*(I don't understand the first row of your expected output)*

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. its working fine with the sample what i have requested. Let me expand my request, as i am looking for the answer for this sample.